# Combining strings to point to objects in R

Tags: arrays, r, object

I have been searching for this answer for weeks and it has to be on here but can't find it anywhere!

Is there a way to combine strings and numbers to point to objects? Basically I have 9 objects called P1, P2, P3 etc and want to access them using a permutation of 9 numbers. I know this doesn't work but this is the idea I am going for.

```
xx=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),9,replace=FALSE)
xx[5]
a=paste("P",xx[5],sep="")
```

I want object a to be the object P5 now (or whatever number xx[5] is). But paste makes it a string P5 rather than pointing to the object.

Is there any other way to go at this?

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious question is why you have nine objects `P1` … `P9` rather than a vector `P` of nine elements.

Comment: The objects are each 25x25 transition matrices, so thought objects would be the best way to do that. Would a vector be better for that? I'm an intermediate R user, so I mainly know how to do a lot of stuff, but pretty much everything I do is the least effective way to do it! @KonradRudolph

Comment: @BaseballR Yeah you’d definitely use a list of matrices. Numbered variables are essentially *never* the right solution (there may be exceptions but I’ve never (!) come across one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get`is the function you are looking for.

```
set.seed(0)
P5 <- "I am P5"
xx=sample(1:9,9,replace=FALSE)
xx[5]
a=paste0("P",xx[5])
get(a)

[1] "I am P5"
```

`get` will search for the object by its name...

**Addendum** : Concerning the question from @Konrad Rudolph above: You could store the matrices in a list object. This is usually the way to go, rather than cluttering up the workspace.

```
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- matrix(1:9, 3) 
l[[2]] <- matrix(9:1, 3)
```

And to get matrix one again:

```
l[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you! So easy, yet so far away from what I was trying!

Answer (score 1):

Usually one would have these 9 objects in a list:

```
stuff <- list(p1, p2, etc)
```

To access them in a random order:

```
stuff[sample(1:9)] # permuted
```

This is much easier than fiddling with eval, get, and their friends. All you need to learn is the difference btw `[`, `[[`, and `$` (ways of accessing the lists' elements).

Additionally, list elements can have names but this is not obligatory. You can access elements by name as `stuff$p1` or `stuff[["p1"]]` (if they have names) or by numeric indices like `stuff[[1]]`. You can add or change all names at once with eg. `names(stuff)<-paste0("p",1:9)` or calculate column means for all elements with `lapply(stuff, colMeans)`. In short, there are lots of useful things you can do with lists, which would be much more complicated and less reliable to achieve using  separate objects in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is `eval` combined with `as.name`:

```
> P1 = "p1 object"
> a = paste("P",1,sep="")
> eval(as.name(a))
[1] "p1 object"
```